# Migration from Play framework 2.0.4 to 2.2.0

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have an application build on top of the Play framework 2.0.4. I would like to migrate it to the newest version (which is currently 2.2.0).

So I've updated my local Play framework installation, all build files accordingly:

**build.properties**:

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

**Build.scala**:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "demagog"
    val appVersion      = "1.0.0"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
        javaCore,
        "com.google.code.morphia" % "morphia" % "0.99",
        "com.google.code.morphia" % "morphia-logging-slf4j" % "0.99",
        "net.tanesha.recaptcha4j" % "recaptcha4j" % "0.0.7"
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
        // Add your own project settings here     

        resolvers += "Morphia repository" at "http://morphia.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/"
    )

}
```

**plugins.sbt**:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

Then I tried to "eclipsify" my project. So I run exactly these two commands:

```
play clean-all
play eclipse
```

and I get lots of errors like:

```
[error] ..\Api.java:11: error: package org.codehaus.jackson does not exist
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
```

which is expected due to the fact I found in the [Migration guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22):

> We have upgraded Jackson to version 2 which means that the package name is now com.fasterxml.jackson.core instead of org.codehaus.jackson.

But at the end of "play eclipse" command I get this error:

```
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Could not create Eclipse project files:
[error] Error evaluating task 'dependencyClasspath': error
```

So the project is not "eclipsified" and I can't use it nor edit in my Eclipse IDE. This compiling on backgroung outside of the Eclipse IDE is really painfull and prevents me from productive using Play framework :-/

Comment: Have you considered changing all imports from `org.codehaus.jackson` to `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`?

Comment: Well, my whole application has about 50 errors due to the new 2.2.0 api. I would like to create the eclipse project with all referenced libraries on the classpath so I could repair those errors in the Eclipse IDE and not in text editor one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete all source code files, generate the IDE files and then restore the source code from version control.

Comment: That is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly that is how the eclipse (and idea) plugin work, you will have to have a working project before you can re-export the project from SBT to eclipse. So you will just have to work through the compilation errors without the usual support from eclipse.